# Sharing UI components between Salesforce and public website

Tags: lightning, ui

We would like to write some UI widgets that we need for our internal users using the Lightning Experience infrastructure but we already know tomorrow we might want to expose them on a public website with different styling.

What is the suggested approach to share code between these two world?

Answer (score 1):

Although still in Beta, you can refer to the [LightningOut documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out.htm), basically:

> Use Lightning Out to run Lightning components apps outside of
>   Salesforce servers. Whether it’s a Node.js app running on Heroku, a
>   department server inside the firewall, or even SharePoint, build your
>   custom app with Force.com and run it wherever your users are.

there are some [requirements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_requirements.htm) involved:

> The remote web container, or origin server, must support the
>   following.
>
> - Ability to modify the markup served to the client browser, including    both HTML and JavaScript.
> - You need to be able to add the Lightning Out markup.
> - Ability to acquire a valid Salesforce session ID. This will most    likely require you to configure a Connected App for the origin
>     server.
> - Ability to access your Salesforce instance. For example, if the    origin server is behind a firewall, it needs permission to access the 
>     Internet, at least to reach Salesforce.
>
> Your Salesforce org must be configured to allow the following.
>
> - The ability for the origin server to authenticate and connect. This    will most likely require you to configure a Connected App for the
>     origin server.
> - The origin server must be added to the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing    (CORS) whitelist.

Alongisde the [dependencies](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_dependencies.htm):

> A Lightning dependency app must do the following.
>
> - Set access control to GLOBAL.
> - Extend from either ltng:outApp or ltng:outAppUnstyled.
> - List as a dependency every component that is referenced in a call to    $Lightning.createComponent().